# wanting to use variable to access class member

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a class clsPowerAtt

```
Public customerName As String
Public customerSoc As String


sub test ()
  Dim oPowerEntry As New clsPowerAtt

  dim members(5) as string
  members(0) = customerName
  members(1) =customerSoC
  dim entry as variant

  for each entry in members

    oPowerEntry .entry = "foo"

  next each
end sub
```

I want to cycle through an array which defines members of the class, such that I don't need to call directly. It doesn't like using variable to point to class member

```
oPowerEntry .entry = "foo"
```

How do I tell vba to evaluate entry

Comment: Have you tried using Enum? Tho I'm not sure this is possible. I typically use a Class Constructor to set my class object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Class Constructor. In this example the constructor is called "init" (for initialize)

your private class properties

```
Private pinp1 As Double
Private pinp2 As Double
Private pinp3 As Double
Private pinp4 As Double
Private pinp5 As Double
```

And your constructor. Here you can pass all five (or however many) of your properties as parameters of the Public Sub. Of course you will need to substitute the names of my properties with yours and the data types. This is just an example of a basic constructor.

```
Public Sub init(ByVal inp1 As Variant, ByVal inp2 As Variant, ByVal inp3 As Variant, _
            ByVal inp4 As Variant, ByVal inp5 As Variant)
    '
    ' set the private class variables to your parameters
    pinp1 = CDbl(inp1)
    pinp2 = CDbl(inp2)
    pinp3 = CDbl(inp3)
    pinp4 = CDbl(inp4)
    pinp5 = CDbl(inp5)
End Sub
```